# Excel Data Validation - Limit Character Type & Length

Tags: excel, validation

I am relatively new to excel so apologies for the simple question.

I would like to add data validation to a range of cells in Excel, the cells will be used to collect "Full Names". I would like the cells to only allow: Text Input (All letters in alphabet both lower and upper case) and have a character length of 1-70.

Im aware of the custom forumla in the Data Validation window however im unsure of the correct command. I have also tried using "Text Length" however this still allows the input of numbers and symbols.

Thanks!

Comment: Data validation has an option "Text Length" which I believe is what you are looking for

Comment: I have tried Text Length, it still allows me to insert numbers and symbols. Sorry i should of stated what ive tried in the post.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58959283/edit) to clarify it. Also, please define what you mean exactly by "text input"

Comment: Why have you not responded to the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `Custom` section:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT((MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1) >="A")*(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1) <="Z"))=LEN(A1),LEN(A1)<=70)
```

It checks, case insensitive, that all of the entries are in the range `[A-Za-z]` and that the length is not longer than 70.

If you want to allow spaces in the entry, then you can add that test as shown below:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT((MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1) >="A")*(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1) <="Z") + (MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1) =" "))=LEN(A1),LEN(A1)<=70)
```

Comment: @TLC Error msg can be ignored. When you add DV to a cell, replace `A1` with the cell ref of the cell you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Same

```
=AND(LEN(A1)<=70,ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(1:999),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&<>"))))
```